# Numpy / Scipy - Sparse matrix to vector

Tags: numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have sparse CSR matrices (from a product of two sparse vector) and I want to convert each matrix to a flat vector. Indeed, I want to avoid using any dense representation or iterating over indexes.

So far, the only solution that came up was to iterate over non null elements by using coo representation:

```
import numpy
from scipy import sparse as sp
matrices = [sp.csr_matrix([[1,2],[3,4]])]*3
vectorSize = matrices[0].shape[0]*matrices[0].shape[1]
flatMatrixData = []
flatMatrixRows = []
flatMatrixCols = []
for i in range(len(matrices)):
    matrix = matrices[i].tocoo()
    flatMatrixData += matrix.data.tolist()
    flatMatrixRows += [i]*matrix.nnz
    flatMatrixCols += [r+c*2 for r,c in zip(matrix.row, matrix.col)]
flatMatrix = sp.coo_matrix((flatMatrixData,(flatMatrixRows, flatMatrixCols)), shape=(len(matrices), vectorSize), dtype=numpy.float64).tocsr()
```

It is indeed unsatisfying and inelegant. Does any one know how to achieve this in an efficient way?

Comment: Your `flatMatrix` is (3,4); each row is `[1 3 2 4]`.  If a submatrix is `x`, then the row is `x.A.T.flatten()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your flatMatrix is (3,4); each row is [1 3 2 4]. If a submatrix is `x`, then the row is `x.A.T.flatten()`.

```
F = sp.vstack([x.T.tolil().reshape((1,vectorSize)) for x in matrices])
```

`F` is the same (dtype is int).  I had to convert each submatrix to `lil` since `csr` has not implemented `reshape` (in my version of `sparse`).  I don't know if other formats work.

Ideally `sparse` would let you do the whole range of `numpy` array (or matrix) manipulations, but it isn't there yet.

Given the small dimensions in this example, I won't speculate on the speed of the alternatives.

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I was looking for. As you pointed out, `flatten()` or `reshape()` are not available for most sparse matrices. I didn't know lil matrices could be reshaped. Thanks!